# Apache user - Permission denied

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos7

I have a problem with my Apache user. He seems to have no right on linux system.
I use CentOS 7, Apache 2.4.6, PHP 5.5.21. The apache user is apache:apache
When I try to use `chmod()` or `fopen()` I get "Permission denied"
So I have created a file named info.php :

```
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache   50 Jan 30 13:55 info.php
```

In this file I just added this line :

```
<?php chmod("info.php", 777); ?>
```

And the result is :

```
Warning: chmod(): Permission denied in /var/www/html/info.php on line 1
```

So I think that the probelm is, system user Apache has no rights but I don't know how can I fix tis?

Thanks.

**EDIT :** fix php code

Comment: pls output ls -la php400_ini.php

Comment: sorry it was a mistake, in my PHP code I try to chmod info.php

Comment: To confirm the username used by httpd : `[root@xxx html]# ps aux | grep apache
apache   26278  0.0  0.7 614668 13764 ?        S    14:07   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND`

Comment: You're on a host right? Why not just use their admin or FTP to change file permissions?

Comment: runs php under apache? to check var_dump(system('whoami'));

Comment: The php script needs to open, read and write files, chmod was just an example, so I don't want to use FTP. the var_dump returns `apache string(6) "apache"`

Comment: Fixed! It was beceause of SELinux

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the chmod with wrong parameter.

```php
chmod("filename", 0777);
```

Please refer to the PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php